# How to expose private method to unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-4.0

I'm trying to expose my private method to unit testing. I  saw this example in [UnitTesting Succintly](http://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks/unittesting):

```
public class DoesSomething
{
#if TEST
    public
#else
    private
#endif
    void SomeComputation() {
    }
}
```

Here is my attempted at it but the code still appears private when trying to access via test.

```
#if TEST
            public
#else
        private
#endif
        Organization TransformToOrganization(OrgChartOrganizationUnitType org)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: While the accepted answer does help with your initial question, it's really worth noting that this is *not* how you write unit tests.  What you're attempting is bad practice in a couple of different ways.  First of all, testing private methods is an invalid case of unit tests.  Second, by using these `TEST` flags you're compiling *entirely different code* for your tests than for your production output, so the tests aren't actually validating anything.

Comment: Also, not seeing the context in the book, if the book *really* does recommend unit testing your private methods, get a new book. I'm sorry, it's just not a good practice at all.

Comment: Sorry for posting so late, but as the author of the accepted answer I have to agree with @David and others stating how bad an idea this is.  I answered to the initial question, but this is so wrong to do I had to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your TEST compile constant properly.  That's not one that's built into to VS compile constants that get switched on/off for Debug/Release configurations.

Answer (score 15):

You shouldn't need to expose *private* methods to your tests. The *public* methods of your class have a specification. Your unit tests should be testing that the *public* methods of your class adhere to that specification. How the *public* methods go about doing that is no one's business; you want to be free to change your *private* implementation however you like as long as you continue to adhere to the specification of your *public* methods.

If you write unit tests that depend on the *private* implementation, you end up with incredibly brittle unit tests that don't actually add any value because the *only* thing that you need to validate is that the *publicly* exposed members adhere to their specification. If there are little kittens running around hidden in the background making the whole thing work, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Good answer! Also you can make internals visible by adding a line to the AssemblyInfo.cs file: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyNameSpace.UnitTest")]`

Comment: @jason Yes, but your **private implementation should still work**, and unit tests should be small. Testing a larger public function, and ignoring the private functions it calls, simply tells you one of the private functions it's comprised of has failed. It doesn't tell you which one.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to expose my private method to unit testing.

You shouldn't.  Private methods are just that, private.  They are fully encapsulated within the class which contains them and not part of the external interface of that class.  The unit tests should validate the external-interface (or externally visible functionality) of the class, not its private internal implementation.

To put it another way, writing tests for private methods tightly couples the tests to the specific implementations of those objects.

The private methods should be tested indirectly when they are used by the public-facing functionality of the objects.  If they're not covered in those tests, you have two options:

- There is functionality not being tested, so the tests are incomplete. Or;
- The private methods aren't being used and should be removed.